# Does hex-rays support VLA in any way?

Tags: ida, c, hexrays, array

I was testing some 'C' code with VLAs. It wasn't that surprising that Hex-Rays was not able to recognize VLA. As with structures there is some way to make it understand (simply making the variable type of the structure you think it is) - is there similar thing for VLAs?

Comment: you could simply call malloc() after obtaining the size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Hexrays does not support this.

Following the instructions for variable-length arrays (https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/tutorials/varstr/index.shtml) shows that it does work for IDA disassembly and Set Type (hotkey Y), but not in the decompiler output (Hexrays).

Example source:

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
  int b;
  char c[0];
} foo;

int main() {
  foo* f = malloc(512);
  f->c[123] = 0;
}
```

Struct defined in IDA:

```
00000000 struc_1         struc ; (sizeof=0x8, mappedto_1, variable size)
00000000 a               dd ?
00000004 b               dd ?
00000008 c               db 0 dup(?)             ; XREF: main+1D/w
00000008 struc_1         ends
```

Example disassembly after annotation:

```
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
and     esp, 0FFFFFFF0h
sub     esp, 20h
mov     dword ptr [esp], 200h ; size
call    _malloc
mov     [esp+1Ch], eax
mov     eax, [esp+1Ch]
mov     [eax+(struc_1.c+7Bh)], 0
leave
retn
```

Example decompiled output:

```
int __cdecl main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **envp)
{
  struc_1 *result; // eax@1

  result = (struc_1 *)malloc(0x200u);
  BYTE3(result[0x10].a) = 0;
  return (int)&result->a;
}
```